# building simple http client in c

Tags: c, sockets, http

```
sprintf(send_data,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n",hoststr);
printf("%s",send_data);
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
while(bytes_recieved)
  {
    bytes_recieved=recv(sock,recv_data,1024,0);
    printf("%d\n",bytes_recieved);
    if(bytes_recieved==0){ break; }
    recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';
    printf("%s" , recv_data);
  }
```

When I request for example "www.example.com",
I get the whole page and then at the end after two or three seconds I get bytes_received printed ('0') and then the loop breaks.

Why it takes 2-3 seconds to break the loop?

Is there a better way to implement simple http client then this?

Thanks.

Comment: At a guess? Keep-alive. Try using "HTTP/1.0"

Comment: HTTP/1.0 works without waiting 2-3 seconds why is that?

Comment: By default, HTTP 1.1 uses "Connection: Keep-Alive".  This is because most web pages have more than one file that needs to be downloaded from the server; you don't have to reconnect to get the CSS for example.  I believe you can get this behavior in HTTP 1.1 by specifying "Connection: Close" in the headers.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use `1.1` you should probably add an "Accept" header. See also [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) and [persistent connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `recv` returns `0` it means that the other end of the connection has nicely closed the connection.

HTTP is, from the beginning, a pure request-response protocol, where each request got a response followed by a closed connection.

What you're seeing here is that first you receive the requested page, then after a timeout (due to the newer versions of the HTTP protocol (that you say you support) keeps the connection open) a closed connection from the server.

Answer (score 1):

As an optimization for the HTTP protocol, version 1.1 adds default persistent connections (aka `Connection: Keep-Alive`). The [keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) holds the connection open so that you can send additional requests over the "reliable" channel; you can find additional information about that portion of the HTTP protocol in [RFC2616 Section 8.1 - Persistent Connections](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html).